# User directed bitmap change

Tags: python-2.7, bitmap, wxpython

I am coding with Python 2.7, and I am trying to change the background bitmap image based on a user's radio button selection from a drop down menu in a different window.  In the code attached, the Bitmap0 image is the default.  By selecting "Photo" menu, then the "Change Photo" menu item, causes a radio box to appear.  I want to be able to select Bitmap1 and have the bitmap image change to the Bitmap1 image.

I have unsuccessfully tried pubsub, and I was never confident with how the pubsub module fit into Python.  Isn't this possible through accessing the right variables in the right way?

My simplified code is as follows:

```
import wx

IPaa0 = 0

bgphoto = "bitmap" + str(IPaa0) + ".bmp"
print bgphoto

_ID_Item0 = wx.NewId()
_ID_Item1 = wx.NewId()
_ID_Item2 = wx.NewId()
_ID_Item3 = wx.NewId()
_ID_Item4 = wx.NewId()
_ID_Item5 = wx.NewId()


class cPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    def TogFot(self, fotnum):
        print "TogFot Entered"


class aFotoDir(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        iMainFrame = cMainFrame("Top Frame", (0, 0), (1200, 900))
        iMainFrame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(iMainFrame)
        return True


class cMainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title, pos, size)
        iPanel = cPanel(self)


        MenuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        mFile = wx.Menu()
        MenuBar.Append(mFile, "File")

        mFoto = wx.Menu()
        MenuBar.Append(mFoto, "Photo")

        self.SetMenuBar(MenuBar)


        MenuItem0 = wx.Menu()
        mFile.Append(_ID_Item0, "Open")

        MenuItem1 = wx.Menu()
        mFile.Append(_ID_Item1, "Save")

        MenuItem2 = wx.Menu()
        mFile.Append(_ID_Item2, "Save As")

        MenuItem3 = wx.Menu()
        mFile.Append(_ID_Item3, "Close")

        MenuItem4 = wx.Menu()
        mFile.Append(_ID_Item4, "Exit")


        MenuItem5 = wx.Menu()
        mFoto.Append(_ID_Item5, "Change Photo")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.ClickChFoto, id = _ID_Item5)


        img0 = wx.Image(bgphoto, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        img1 = wx.StaticBitmap(iPanel, -1, wx.BitmapFromImage(img0))


    def ClickChFoto(self, event):

        iSecondFrame = cSecondFrame("Input", (50, 0), (400, 300))
        iSecondFrame.Show()
        return True


class cSecondFrame(cMainFrame):

        def __init__(self, title, pos, size):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title, pos, size)
            iSecondPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

            iBut0 = wx.Button(iSecondPanel, -1,     "OK", pos = ( 75, 200))
            iBut1 = wx.Button(iSecondPanel, -1, "CANCEL", pos = (225, 200))

            Plist = ["Bitmap0", "Bitmap1"]

            self.iWid0 = wx.RadioBox(iSecondPanel, -1, "Photo Selection", (50, 50),
                                     (200, 100), Plist, 1, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)

            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ClickOK,     iBut0)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ClickCANCEL, iBut1)


        def ClickOK(self, event):
            print "OK Clicked"
            global IPaa0
            IPaa0 = self.iWid0.GetSelection()
            print IPaa0
            global bgphoto
            bgphoto = "bitmap" + str(IPaa0) + ".bmp"
            print bgphoto
            self.Close(True)


        def ClickCANCEL(self, event):
            print "CANCEL Clicked"
            self.Close(True)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = aFotoDir(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The image files are just two files with the titles "Bitmap0" and "Bitmap1".  I didn't know the protocol for uploading images, and they were each over 6 MB in size, so I didn't upload.

I would appreciate any guidance and instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference of `cFrame` to `cSecondFrame` as a parameter to the `__init__` of `cSecondFrame`. Then from within its `def ClickOK` load the new bitmap as before and set it in `img1` and call the `Layout()` function of `cFrame`.

Comment: Hmmm.  Thanks user 2963623.  You have exposed another gap in my knowledge, I don't know how to do this.  I am going back to Lutz's O'Reilly book to fill the gap.  Do you have another suggested reference?

Comment: user2963623, since you are the only one to attempt to assist me, may I ask you to please modify my code to implement your suggestion.  It isn't clear to me how to reference cMainFrame in the __init__ of cSecondFrame and then use it?  I got an error message that said that I had too many arguments when I add cMainFrame as an argument to cSecondFrame's __init__.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll have a look at it.  Give me a few days